# How to group by collectors for List of Inner Class?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to group by url in my inner class.

I have:

```
public class TripUpdateRequestDtos {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<TripUpdateRequestDto> requestList = new java.util.ArrayList<TripUpdateRequestDto>();

    public List<TripUpdateRequestDto> getRequestList() {
        return requestList;
    }

    public void setRequestList(List<TripUpdateRequestDto> requestList) {
        this.requestList = requestList;
    }

    public void addReqInfo(String apiKey,Long jobTripId, String url)
    {
        requestList.add(new TripUpdateRequestDto(apiKey,jobTripId, url));
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class TripUpdateRequestDto
    {
        private String apiKey;
        private Long jobTripId;

        @JsonIgnore
        private String url;

    }
}
```

And I want to group by using map and Java 8 stream:

```
Map<String, List<TripUpdateRequestDto>> tripMap = tripUpdateRequestDtos.getRequestList().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(???What shall I place here????));
```

The Collectors.groupingBy should group according to url. What shall I place in Collectors.groupingBy() ?

Please help and ask me if I am unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Uhm... what is the question here?

Comment: `TripUpdateRequestDto::getUrl`? Assuming `getRequestList()` returns a collection of `TripUpdateRequestDto`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<TripUpdateRequestDto>> tripMap =   
    tripUpdateRequestDtos.getRequestList()
                         .stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TripUpdateRequestDto::getUrl));
```

Where `getUrl` is the method that returns `url`.

Comment: Hi! I am getting error: The type TripUpdateRequestDtos.TripUpdateRequestDto does not define getURL(T) that is applicable here

Comment: @AlanTT Do you have a getter method of some other name that returns `url`?

Comment: the `@Getter` from lombok replace the ordinary getter

Comment: @YCF_L Does it generate some implicit getter method? When is it generated?

Comment: It is from lombok. @Eran

Comment: Yes it do, the same, your solution is correct, I think the OP have some other issues

Comment: Thanks @Eran, it should be getUrl, not getURL. My mistake.